# In Elder Sign, can I use Jenny Barnes' ability to discard a spell when the mythos lingering effect bars investigators from using spells?

Tags: elder-sign

Can I use Jenny's ability to discard a spell to gain the dice, because discarding is not the same as 'using' a spell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.**  Special effects that refer to discarding a card do not count as using the card.